# iOS development - launch screens where image on main screen can change?

Tags: ios, xcode, mobile-development

So I am new to iOS development and I have a question about the launch screen.

My app will have an image (that loads when the app opens from the internet) this can change anytime the image is updated on the website, so what is the done thing when designing a launch screen as the image could be different to what is on the launch screen?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Apple's [Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/graphics/launch-screen/), they suggest that the launch screen should match the first screen of your app. In the example they give, the only parts of the launch screen are the non-dynamic parts (the UI around the web content).

> Design a launch screen that’s nearly identical to the first screen of your app. If you include elements that look different when the app finishes launching, people can experience an unpleasant flash between the launch screen and the first screen of the app.

The launch screen is presented before your app loads, and it should be used for static content only.

If there are any UI elements around the image that is displayed, show those in your launch screen. If not, choose a neutral background color that works well with the theme of your app.

Answer (score 1):

Omit the image. A launch image should be a bare outline of what the screen will *certainly* contain. It might be no more than the correctly-colored background. It is just to cover the gap between nothing and something.

Read the Guidelines: https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/graphics/launch-screen/ Look at the picture on the left. That's a launch screen — basically empty.

Comment: I have read the guidelines and it says that it should not include logos or any loading screens.... so what I will do is to include all the elements on the main screen and where the image goes is just leave it blank.... it also says that I should not include any text (my buttons have text on them so are they saying the launch screen should show the buttons without the text?

Comment: Yes anything that is potentially dynamic should not be in the launch screen. The buttons should not have text because you may want to translate your app for different languages.

Comment: Ah I get it. I was just going to screen shot the app screen and use that but now I understand exactly what I need to do

Answer (score 0):

LaunchScreen image is always the same.. 
You can set it in LaunchScreen.storyboard

Answer (score 0):

The launch screen is used to display something whilst your app is initialising, making network requests or whatever.

You shouldn't be looking to load dynamic content here as if a user is on a very slow connection then they wont see anything until your image has loaded. This is why it doesn't have a view controller associated with it. it should be static.

You should only really be loading your logo or something in here, you could just use the company name. it will only show for a short amount of time. then when assets change, submit the changes to store

Comment: Apple's HIG discourage using the launch screen as a branding opportunity. With faster and faster devices, the launch screen appears for such a short period of time that any logo or image that appears will distract the user.

Comment: I've only ever seen a company logo or something in there, what do you put there?

Comment: The "Apple way" is to put an image that resembles your user interface. If you follow the link on my question you'll see an example. A lot of apps have switched to this (instead of a company logo) because of how short the load times are now.